# How to disable jackrabbit.log_IS_UNDEFINED in jackrabbit-standalone-2.4.2.jar

Tags: java, jackrabbit

I have created a code using jackrabbit-standalone-2.4.2.jar and i am getting jackrabbit.log_IS_UNDEFINED.log file in the project directory. This log file is very huge(close to 1 GB). I want to disable it but i dont know how. Does anybody have any idea to deal with situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove this file you have to (as stated in the file name) to define the logger that you want to use.

Since jackrabbit is relying on slf4j, you should configure properly a logger for it.

For instance you can add to you dependencies the lf4j-log4j12 implementation, plus a log4j.properties in your classpath.

You can also configure any other slf4j implementation.

Comment: I have created my log4j.properties and it is creating log file but it does not contain any logs. I have added slf4j and log4j jar files to the classpath. Now all applications logs are written to this jackrabbit.log_IS_UNDEFINED.log file. what am i suppose to do

Comment: Have also added the slf4j-log4jxx.jar in the classpath? This one makes the link from slf4j to log4j. Without it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by removing logback.xml and slf4j.jar from jackrabbit-standalone.jar  and adding slf4j.jar and slf4j-lo4j.jar in the classpath of the project. Now jackrabbit.log_IS_UNDEFINED.log is gone and i am getting desired logs :)